# Scala conflicting inherited method names

Tags: scala, testing, namespaces, scalatest

I am trying to write some code to test a database model. Both the test framework and the database framework use the "===" operator, and the test framework's is being given preference. How can I explicitly use one method or the other?

Example:

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite

class TestDBModels extends FunSuite{
  test("Test DoublePropertyEntry with a few new values") {
    Schemas.doubleProperties.deleteWhere(p => (p.id === p.id)))
  }
}
```

Error:

```
type mismatch;
found   : Option[String]
required: org.squeryl.dsl.ast.LogicalBoolean
Schemas.doubleProperties.deleteWhere(p => (p.===(p.id, p.id)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a number of options. The first and easiest is to use an explicit method call instead of the implicit conversion. For example, to explicitly use the scalatest ===:

```
Schemas.doubleProperties.deleteWhere(p => (convertToEqualizer(p.id) === p.id)))
```

If this is too long, you could shorten the name:

```
def toEq(left: Any) = convertToEqualizer(left: Any)
Schemas.doubleProperties.deleteWhere(p => (toEq(p.id) === p.id)))
```

convertToEqualizer is the implicit conversion method for scalatest. One other option is to override convertToEqualizer as a non-implicit method:

```
override def convertToEqualizer(left: Any) = new Equalizer(left)
```

This stops this particular implicit conversion happening. See the [scalatest documentation for Assertions object](http://scalatest.org/scaladoc/1.6.1/org/scalatest/Assertions%24.html) and the [same question on the scalatest-users mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scalatest-users/UoZdZkvK1Us).

Comment: The important point here is the override of the implicit def, to something not implicit. That will turn off automatic use of scalatest's `===` method. Then, **if** you want to use Assertions and scalatest's `===`, you can explicity invoke convertToEqualizer, or simply `new Equalizer`. Personally I would use `ShouldMatchers` instead, as I prefer `a should equal (b)` to the more imperative sounding `assert(a === b)`, or in this case, `assert(toEq(a) === b)`.